# Property does not exist on type component or object in Angular 15

Tags: angular15

I have upgraded angular CLI 7 to 15 version, so I'm getting every time application when I'm running getting the error **property does not exist if property exist also I'm getting same error**. how can I resolve 'property does not exist' kind of issues.

example:

```
    `error: TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Object'.

<td>{{eachmodel.name| slice:0:15}}</td>`
```

`error: TS2339: Property 'CP' does not exist on type 'component'. <span (Click)="EditSegmentItem(CP.pk_ID, CP.fk_segmentID)"></span>`

component.ts:

```
EditSegmentItem(pk_ID:any, fk_segmentID: any){
let self = this;
self.fk_complianceID = pk_ID;
self.segmentPID = fk_segmentID;
this.editSegmentItemModel = new CompliLibrarySegmentData();
if(result.compiances){
 let index= result.compiances.findIndex(item => item.pk_ID == pk_ID);
 if(index > -1){
  self.editSegmentItemModel = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.compiances[index]));
 }
}
}
```

Please suggest solution for how to resolve such kind of '**property does not exist**' issues.

Comment: Can you provide some code

Comment: Hi, @kuuhak-u, I have edited my question with added some code Please check